# Create file array object when new file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want create array of file-type like below in JavaScript.

e.g     `File[] filesl = new File[1];`

or `List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();`

But it doesn't help me.

I need to have array of files.

Comment: An array in Javascript is not typed, so you can just create an array, and put files on it

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of java. Javascript (which is a different language) currently does not have typed variables. To create an array in javascript, you would do

```
var files = [];
```

You can put anything you want into this array, including file data.